# multiple occurrence of the same thing in python list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to implement a postscript interpreter in python. For this part of the program, I'm trying to access multiple occurrences of the same element in a list, but the function call does not do that. I can explain it better with the code.

This loop steps through a list of tokens

```
for token in tokens:
    process_token(token)
```

tokens is define as:

```
line = "/three 3 def /four 4 def"
tokens = line.strip().split(" ")
```

So after this is done tokens looks like ['/three', '3', 'def', '/four', '4', 'def'].

Process tokens will continue to push thing on to a stack until it reaches an operation to be done, in this case def. Once it gets to def it will execute:

```
if (t == "def"):
   handle_def (tokens.index(t)-2, tokens.index(t)-1)
   stack.pop()
```

and here is handle_def():

```
def handle_def (t, t1):
name = tokens[t]
defin = tokens [t1]
x=name[1:]
dict1 [x]= float(defin)
```

The problem is when it is done adding {'three':3} to the dictionary, it then should keep reading and add {'four':4} to the dictionary. But when `handle_def (tokens.index(t)-2, tokens.index(t)-1)` is called it will pass in the index numbers for the first occurrence of def, meaning it just puts {'three':3} into the dictionary again. I want it to skip past the first one and go the later occurrences of the word def. How do I make it do that?

Sorry for the long post, but i felt like it needed the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.index` will give only the first occurrence in the list. You can use the [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to get the index of the current item being processed, like this

```
for index, token in enumerate(tokens):
    process_token(index, token)
...
...
def process_token(index, t):
    ...
    if t == "def":
        handle_def (index - 2, index - 1)
    ...
```

Comment: I will, but it says i have to wait 4 minutes.

Comment: @Finalreq Moreover, you can split like this `line.split()`, you don't have to pass space character. `split` will split based on the whitespace characters.

Comment: That is useful to know. Thank you.